# Inkscape - Aligning imported image to axonometric grid

Tags: inkscape

I am building a map of our outdoor retail store and am using a screenshot from Google Maps satellite view as a guide. I want this map to be isometric/axonometric and have set my grid up with a 26.5 degree angle on both the X and Y.

Since it is difficult to align a view in Google Maps to exactly a 26.5 degree angle, I would rather align this guide image in Inkscape; however, I can't figure out how to get it lined up at a reasonably precise position.

How can I align/transform the image on the right so that it matches the green object on the left?

[image: Example alignment]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Begin with a regular rectangular or square image. The original in the example below is an exact square, so you can see the distortion clearly.

1. Scale vertically 86.602%
2. Skew horizontal -30°
3. Rotate 30°

[image]

After this, you can scale it to any size by simply holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as you click and drag one of the scale handles to constrain the aspect ratio.

Example showing positioning and scaling to fit the grid.

[image]

Comment: How do you get the scale amount? What is the significance of 86.062%? I was going for a 26.5 degree angle, but I suppose 30 degrees works as well.

Comment: @pspahn - sorry, I didn't calculate it. I just [looked it up online](https://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-advanced-isometric-illustrations-using-the-ssr-method--vector-1058). I'm no mathematician!

Comment: You can also install the [isometric projection extension](https://github.com/jdhoek/inkscape-isometric-projection) which does all the job.

Comment: @Juancho - excellent! But then I'd probably have to look up how to install it, and then learn how to use it, which would likely take longer. LOL

Comment: @BillyKerr Ah yes, I see in the comments some discussion on the formula to find the scale factor (which they say should actually be 86.602). It seems to come from the difference in length of the sides after skewing - ie: 100px square skewed 30deg leaves sides of 100px and 115.47 - 100/115.47=86.6025808

Comment: @pspahn - that half a percentage error might explain why I found it a little difficult to scale it exactly to the isometric grid. Well spotted. I edited the answer.

Comment: ultimately, it's `(cos30)`, but I never took trig so I'm not sure how to get the proper scaling for a 26.5deg angle. `(cos26.5)` doesn't seem to work properly. I have some existing assets I've drawn that are based on that angle so I'm hoping to figure this out without a few hours of Khan Academy lessons. =)

Comment: @pspahn Maybe you could ask that on Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Last time I did trigonometry was probably in high school, mid 1980s. Lol.

Comment: Aha. Functionally equivalent, instead of scaling -> skewing -> rotating, you can rotate -> scale. For a 30deg angle: rotate 45, scale 57.7350269 (which is simply `(tan30)`). For 26.5deg angle: rotate 45, scale 49.8581608 (which is `(tan26.5)`)

I guess I learned math today.

Comment: @pspahn - I learnt something today too!!  Well done!

Comment: @pspahn there's another [similar answer here on GDSE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/107537/89608) that mentions the possibility of skewing objects to fit an isometric projection using a Matrix Transform, which is essentially just one step.  I've no idea how to work out the numbers to enter into the matrix for your specific 26.5 degree grid unfortunately.

Comment: @pspahn, I explained how to obtain these numbers in [my blog](http://nicoguaro.github.io/posts/isometric_inkscape/).

Answer (score 3):

@BillyKerr gave me the answer I needed and through that I found out a slightly different method which pretty much works the same. I'm including this answer simply because it allows an easy way to figure the correct scale for any arbitrary angle.

Start with a square and rotate 45°

Scale horizontally by finding the tangent of the angle you want to use - in my case, `(tan26.5)`

[image: iso formula]

Comment: You know you can actually choose your own answer as best. My answer is missing the actual maths you needed for your specific 26.5 degree grid, which you worked out yourself. I've upvoted it anyway.

Comment: There is a better way yet. Instead of doing all those individual operations you can just set the individual vectors in the matrix, which is faster an easier to do. No need to copy illustrator specific defiencies. See https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/107509/get-an-image-to-lie-flat-on-an-axonometric-grid-in-inkscape/107537#107537

Answer (score 1):

But there's still ways. This one doesn't need multiplications with numbers.

[image]

1. The wanted final fit of the photo. It's drawn by clicking 5 times with the Pen; snap to grid must be =ON.
2. Applied to 1. rotate 30 degrees CCW and skew +30 degrees horizontally. You must scale your photo to this size. It's easy if you have snap to points all = ON, but snap to grid and bounding boxes = OFF.

3-4. The transformations needed to the photo after scaling. 3=horizontal skew -30 degrees, 4=rotate 30 degrees CW.

In image 1. the proportions are Width:Height = 5:4. If you want to keep the proportions of the photo as undistorted as possible in Isometric projection, but it must still fit into the grid select the proportions of image 1  as closely as possible  the same as the original proportions of your photo.

In Inkscape you can scale images and other shapes proportionally if you hold the Ctrl-key.