How to make a 3d version like this?
I would like to draw the following image in Inkscape:

However, I am stuck in reproducing the 3d version of the above image. I can only draw a 2D version of the above image as follows:

I would appreciate help regarding to make a schematic 3D version of the image shown at the top.

Just draw it from the top view, you can then transform that into a isometric drawing. See: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/107509/get-an-image-to-lie-flat-on-an-axonometric-grid-in-inkscape/107537#107537

The used projection is popular in technical illustrations which contain shapes that have mostly X, Y and Z oriented edges, but do not need to have any accurate drawing scale. All vertical edges are still vertical and some horizontal edges (say in parallel with X-axis), are still horizontal. The geometry is badly distorted when compared to accurate engineering drawings, but it does not harm at all, because this is an illustration of a construction principle.
Accurate engineering drawings have perspective or they use some common parallel projection (isometric, dimetric, trimetric) Parallel projections can be considered perspective images where the observer is distant and uses a telescope.
You obviously have aimed a perspective image, but it doesn't add any value, because the construction principle doesn't need it. Manufacturing drawings are a different case.
As suggested already by others, draw the top wiew and distort it to the wanted projection. Then insert the thickness. Starting from the top wiew instead of drawing directly into projection grid allows searching a good viewing direction. Using a fixed projection grid creates easily unwanted coincident edges or corners.
Approximately right scale is good enough and small parts can well be exaggerated to make them easily visible. Identical parts should be drawn identical. Duplicate to get identical limbs and make a path union or draw with the pen (=Bezier tool) to a rectangular grid. See the next image:

The top view is in the left. The baseplate and the limbs are combined with Path > Union to a single closed shape. The six zone division lines in the limbs are drawn separately with the pen. It snaps perfectly if one has node snapping to midpoints ON.
In the right all is selected and Object > Transform is applied 2 times. The shape is at first scaled vertically to 50% and then -40 degrees horizontal skew is applied. These are not any standard. I selected them for good look (only an opinion). 50% and -40 degrees were found after a couple of Undos.
In this phase it's useful to group the parts to keep them together.
Duplicate the shape. Move the duplicate a little upwards (hold Ctrl or use arrow key):

Then draw with the pen closed shapes to fill the gaps. The pen snaps perfectly if you have all node snaps to other nodes, paths, crossings etc.. ON.
Color the drawn shapes. It's useful to make the vertical surfaces a little darker. The idea is to assume the light comes from a certain direction and surfaces which get as much light look as bright. Shadows are not needed in schematic like illustrations.
In the next image there's a few of surface patches drawn. They can also be duplicated, because the top view had identical limbs and this projection has no perspective, so the equality stays. The drawn surface patches are shown also separately as moved aside.

Use the node tool to move the corners of a surface patch shape if needed. It snaps perfectly if you have snappings ON.
Of course, you may want that the main shape has a proper perspective. It's not hopeless in Inkscape, but to stay in truth, drawing a 3D model in a CAD program is much faster than drawing the shown version or an isometric version in Inkscape. In a CAD program one must draw the top view and then extrude it + select the colors of separate pieces (7 pieces in the next example):

The image has perfect perspective and one can add wires, feeds, part & signal names and other annotations afterwards either in the CAD program or Inkscape.
Making the right perspective succeeds also in Inkscape by applying path effect Perspective Envelope to the top view. The top view must be combined to a single path before applying the effect.
After expanding the effect by applying Path > Object to path one can make a duplicate and draw patches for the vertical surfaces one by one. Perspective makes every surface different, so a duplicate doesn't fit as is. In the next image the perspective envelope dialog is shown. One can adjust the corners with the node tool.

In the bottom the perspective envelope effect  is expanded, a duplicate is made and some vertical surfaces are drawn. Doing the job with perspective in Inkscape is not substantially harder than making my 1st version, but takes easily 400% longer than doing it in a 3D CAD program. The difference is only 400% because the shape is planar, contains only straight edges and is so thin that cheating the the vertical edges (which should be all tilted and have different lengths, but are drawn vertical  and equally long) doesn't cause any disturbing error.
Adjusting the corners of the perspective envelope is based on the experience of the user. Inkscape works in 2D, so there's no way to input the wanted view as the placement, orientation and lens properties of the camera. I had the CAD version on the same computer screen; it was easy to make something resembling. But making a perspective view exactly is a challenge in Inkscape.

Inkscape has no true 3D capabilities, except for very basic 3D cuboid shapes which are in fact not even true 3D anyway, only 2D representations.  Your best bet is probably to enable the Axonometric Grid in the document properties Grids tab.
Then you can enable snapping, and draw objects using the Pen Tool directly on the grid to represent 3D surfaces (in 2D of course), and use different fill colours for the shading, etc.
Here's an example of a partial reconstruction of the original image. Grid settings shown right.
Click to see larger
Here an example showing all of the shapes separated so that you can see how each surface is constructed. Each is a closed path with a fill and stroke applied in the Fill and Stroke panel (shown right).
Click to see larger

Thanks! How you have filled the colors? I am not able to fill the colors inside the path that I draw using the Bezier tool.

@Rakesh You can change the fill colours in the Fill and Stroke panel, Fill tab. Shapes must be closed paths if you want to fill the whole shape. You won't be able to see a fill for single straight lines. My answer assumes you already have a basic understanding of strokes and fills. If you don't then there are beginner tutorials on youtube. Logos by Nick is a particularly good channel.

@Rakesh - I've edited my answer to make this clearer.
